# How can I fill a data table with a URI datatype column from SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, uri, sqldataadapter

I have created a datatable where one column is specified as type URI. This is because I later want to use the table as source for binding to a grid in WPF, autogenerating a grid column with a hyperlink. How can I fill this datatable from my SQL Server database?

Here is my sample code:-

```
 _tblMarketPlaces = new DataTable("MarketPlaces");
 _tblMarketPlaces.Columns.Add("MarketPlaceID");
 _tblMarketPlaces.Columns.Add("MarketPlaceIdentifier");
 _tblMarketPlaces.Columns.Add("MarketPlaceName");
 _tblMarketPlaces.Columns.Add("MarketPlaceHomeUri",typeof(Uri));
 _tblMarketPlaces.Columns.Add("DisplayPriorityOrder");

_tblMarketPlaces.Clear();

_tblMarketPlaces.Rows.Add(0, "N/A", "Unknown", DBNull.Value, 0);

SqlConnection DB = ArtContentManager.Static.Database.DBReadOnly;
string sqlSelectMarketPlaces = "Select * from MarketPlaces Order By DisplayPriorityOrder";
SqlCommand cmdSelectMarketPlaces = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectMarketPlaces, DB);

SqlDataAdapter sdaMarkePlace = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSelectMarketPlaces);
sdaMarkePlace.Fill(_tblMarketPlaces);
```

The problem is that the last fill statement fails because the data type of MarketPlaceHomeUri is nvarchar on the database and isn't recognised as a URI. Is there some way I can persuade the DataAdapter to convert the data in the fill?

[I know another approach would be to have the datatable simply use text for the field and then format the column explicitly in my WPF Xaml but I would like to use autogenerated columns there and this seems possible if only I can load the data into the datatable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem if it helps anyone else. You can handle a Fill error on the data adaptor and do your own thing to override the default fill mechanism and fix a data type on the way.

In my case I added this:-

```
sdaMarkePlace.FillError += new FillErrorEventHandler(FillError);
```

and this, which together did the trick...

```
    private static void FillError(object sender, FillErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Uri rowURI;

        if (args.Errors.GetType() == typeof(System.ArgumentException))
        {
            if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(args.Values[3].ToString(), UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                // The URI is valid. This should be ensured in the database update but don't assume it is for defensive coding reasons
                rowURI = new Uri(args.Values[3].ToString());
                DataRow myRow = args.DataTable.Rows.Add(new object[]
              {args.Values[0], args.Values[1], args.Values[2], rowURI, args.Values[4]});
            }
            else
            {
                // The URI is invalid. Update with a Null value for that field
                DataRow myRow = args.DataTable.Rows.Add(new object[]
             {args.Values[0], args.Values[1], args.Values[2], DBNull.Value, args.Values[4]});
            }

            args.Continue = true;
        }
    }
```

I realise the above logic isn't perfect because it is assuming all Fill argument exceptions are due to the URI issue which may not always be true, but a bit more tweaking should get me to a comprehensive solution. Works nicely with the WPF autogenerated grid columns now.

Comment: Not terribly elegant as there are dependencies on data ordering in the SQL, the data table and the error handling logic itself which somewhat undermine the point of autogenerating columns in the first place and would make it messier than I'd like if the table structure changes, but there are probably ways to make it somewhat more generic. Also if you are expecting an error for every row is that really a good design? But it is a possible solution at least...

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of a URI you want to put in MarketPlaceHomeUri? Maybe it doesn't conform with the URI validation requirement (the part where you call typeof(Uri)). Make the URI as complete as possible (with http://www. or something).

Comment: System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <http://www.renderosity.com/> in MarketPlaceHomeUri Column.  Expected type is Uri.

Comment: The above is my error which is from the first record in my file. I see that stack exchange has converted the text in the error message to a link. In the original raw text it is a full URL which works when copied into a browser address bar and contains the full http:\\ prefix

Comment: If I add a record "manually" to the datatable as per the first dummy example in the code, it works if the value is DBNull.Value or if I explicitly cast as a URI object, which makes sense. I suspect that the Fill method is not casting the string and I am wondering if how/if I can convince it to do that.

Comment: e.g. // This "manual" approach works
       _tblMarketPlaces.Rows.Add(1, "Renderosity", "Renderosity", new Uri("http://www.renderosity.com/"), 1);
      // This fails (and is what I think the Fill is doing)
      _tblMarketPlaces.Rows.Add(2, "Renderosity", "Renderosity", "http://www.renderosity.com/", 2); - Struggling to make the stack exchange editor not try and convert my text into links here so you have to trust that the true text is a correct link.

Comment: How about you cast it in a separate variable first before putting it into your datatable?

Comment: I would like to do that but I didn't see how/where I could intervene between the SQL and the Fill operation. The solution I posted allows this to be done by handling the Fill error and works but doesn't feel like the best way. I am now thinking a cleaner mechanism is maybe not to use a data adaptor at all, but manually add each row in a loop where I would be able to cast before adding, rather than after each inevitable error. That feels neater.